# how to use jquery in aframe

Tags: jquery, aframe

```
<a-gltf-model id="nacl500" src="#bottle" scale="0.1 0.1 0.1" position="-0.27 1.410 -0.83" rotation="0 270 0" 
                bottleactivity__movetocamera="event:movetocamera" bottleactivity__rotatetobacksite="event:rotatetobacksite" bottleactivity__rotatetotopsite="event:rotatetotopsite"
                bottleactivity__movetodesk="event:movetodesk" bottleactivity__takeoffcap="event:takeoffcap" bottleactivity__hang="event:hang">
    <a-gltf-model src="#bottlewaterbottom"></a-gltf-model>
    <a-gltf-model id="bottlecap" src="#bottledecker" position="0 0.904 0"></a-gltf-model>
    <a-gltf-model src="#naci500"></a-gltf-model>
  </a-gltf-model>

init:function(){
var self=this;
var data= this.data;
var el=this.el;
//var $el=$("#nacl500");
var $el=$(el);
var status=0;

this.movetocamera=function(){
  //alert(data.message);
  //el.setAttribute("position", "0 1.054 -0.19");
  //alert($el.position);
  $el.animate({position:'0 1.054 -0.19'},"slow");
};
```

I want to add animation via jquery to aframe. But it dosen't work. Alert($el) shows that $el is a object. $el.position is some code. el.position is undefined.

code is here: https://glitch.com/edit/#!/skill-lab

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JQuery Selectors return an array with all elements meeting the selector citeria. 
Therefore, using the element/id selector You need to refer to elements as  `$el=$("cssSelector")[0];`

like i did here: https://jsfiddle.net/7q6dx45L/1/

---

The jquery [animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) method works on CSS properties, therefore will not work on animating webGL objects (position, rotation, color).
I would suggest using the build in `<a-animation>` or ngoKevins [aframe animation component](https://github.com/ngokevin/aframe-animation-component).
They are build on [tween.js](http://www.createjs.com/tweenjs) ( a-animation ), and [anime.js](http://animejs.com/) (the component)

Comment: Thank you for your replying. I did it as you said. But it still not works. Maybe the reason is tha animate?

Comment: I added the code : $el.animate({position:'1 1 1'}, 300); in you jsfiddle, but it also does nothing.

Comment: @LeMüller sorry I only adressed referencing, updated

Comment: Ok, I understand it now. I have tried to use <a-animation>. It works well. Thank you very much.

Comment: @LeMüller If You don't have further questions, feel free to check the anwser :)